# Using Selenium 2 WebDriver, how do I delete an option in a multi-select, auto-complete field using a CSS WebElement?

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

We are just learning Java/Selenium as our QA is moving towards automation.  I am using Selenium 2 WebDriver for automation.  There are some fields on a form that are multiple-select, auto-complete fields.  Basically, you can type the beginning of something and the field will provide options that match, which you select and it gets added to the field.  You can add as many items as you want (basically the same thing as the "tags" field for submitting this question).  I am trying to delete an added item from this field, but cannot figure out the CSS path.  Firebug shows the following HTML:

```
 <div class="c4i-fieldDiv rel" style="min-height: 36px">
 <div id="groupsDropdown" class="ui-autocomplete-multiple">
 <ul class="ui-autocomplete-multiple-container ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
<li class="ui-autocomplete-token ui-state-active ui-corner-all" data-token-value="testGroup">
<span class="ui-autocomplete-token-label">testGroup</span>
<span class="ui-autocomplete-token-icon ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
```

The code I am using is:

```
WebElement deleteGroup = findElementBySelector("//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li/span");    
deleteGroup.click();
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use this XPath? From what I can see you are selecting the group span itself to try to remove it.

Comment: I get an "element not found" error message.  The path that I am using above was the one IDE showed.  I use IDE as a basis for my tests, then re-write them.

Comment: so for some reason if I add multiple items to the field i can delete the third element with "//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li[3]/span" and the second element with "//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li[2]/span", but I cannot delete the first with the above

Comment: So, first could be deleted as:
"//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li[1]/span"
Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked to delete the third item added:

```
WebElement delrole3 = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li[3]/span");
delrole3.click();
```

changing [3] to any other number that corresponds to an item in the field will work to delete that item.

IDE was not registering the [#] portion for some reason.

Comment: Just another tip, you may or may not know, in firefox & chrome you can test out XPath queries in their respective Developer Tools. By running `$x("//div[@id='groupsDropdown']/ul/li[3]/span")` in the Chrome Developer tools, it will run the XPath query against it for you. Just a little tip to hopefully help debugging XPath a bit easier in the future, if you don't already know about it. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I did not know that.  Always great to learn something new!